# Generate a integer hash from an id that is lower than X?

Tags: php

I need to generate a not unique hash from a database id and i need to set a parameter that the generated hash is not greater than x.

**Example:**

ID: `12312452`

Not greater than `5`!

The crossfoot is `20`. Now i can use a `do-while` to sum the digits. The sum is `2`.

But if i take `54674567`, the crossfoot is `44` and in the end it's `8`...

I need this function for dynamic text. I have an array with some meta description (eg. 5 descriptions) and on each page (a database record with a id) the function have to pick a description. I don't want to save the description in the database.

Comment: Check out the modulo operator, it may be what you are looking for ,`44 % 5 = 4`. `any positive integer % x` will be smaller than `x`

Comment: thanks! I tried some numbers with `x = 5` but the result is often `0`, `2` or `3`. It's not dynamic enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, here is my solution:

```
$numbers = [
    45384,
    44638,
    28213,
    43498,
    21170,
    30211
];

$max = 8;

foreach ($numbers as $key => $value) {
    var_dump( array_sum(str_split(crc32($value))) % $max );
}
```

The result:

```
int(6)
int(1)
int(4)
int(1)
int(4)
int(4)
```